# Select a State with RxJS in Angular 6 doesn't work

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, rxjs6, ngoninit

In a web app I'm using Angular and RxJS 6. The application has a login, the response of the login is a token so, after the login, I save the token in the sessionStorage and then I decode the token to save the current logged in user. This is the state after the login:

[image]

I'm trying to develop this behaviour: if the user go to page "..login" (so in login.components.ts) and if he is already logged in, the application will redirect to the home page.
This is my code inside ngOnInit() in **login.component.ts**:

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.store.select('auth')
     .pipe(take(1),
       map((authState: fromAuth.State) => {
         console.log('test');
         if (authState.authenticated) {
           this.router.navigate(['/home']);
         }
      }));
}
```

This is the Interface of AppState:

```
export interface AppState {
  user: fromProfile.State,
  auth: fromAuth.State,
  core: fromCore.State
}
```

Testing it, I login, I go to home, then I go to login page, I put a breakpoint in the console.log() but it doesn't reach the breakpoint, it doesn't even enter it, and so it doesn't redirect to home page. Why?

*** UPDATED ***: this is the screen of debug
[image]

Comment: Is your issue only about your breakpoint ?

Comment: No, the issue is that it doesn't navigate to home even if the user is logged in

Comment: Well, `ngOnInit() {
  .pipe(take(1),` isn't really proper code ... Is it your actual code ?

Comment: yes! I guess it is not the really proper code.....seeing that it doesn't work :D how can I fix it?

Comment: Ah no wait LOL I forgot a line

Comment: I edited my question, I added 'this.store.select('auth')'

Comment: That seems more correct now :D did you try removing the `take(1)` ?

Comment: :) yes, and it doesn't work, same behaviour

Comment: Okay, and is your cde running `ngOnInit` ? Did you try logging before calling store.select ?

Comment: in the ngOnInit () method it enters correctly

Comment: Okay, could you then post the code of `store.select` ?

Comment: Of course, here is a screen of the debugging: https://ibb.co/iB4r9y

Comment: Corporate proxy, I can't see the images. Can't you just post your code here as an [edit] ?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: I still can't see images !

Comment: Mmm.. that's weird! Well, I'm going to describe: if a debug  const test = this.store.select('auth'); it is an object of type Store, with has these properties: actionsObserver, operator, reducerManager, source, _isScalar: false

Comment: Not weird, my work place blocks imgur ... I know `store.select` is an Observable, but I want to see how you wrote it. Unless it's coming from a library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select()` function returns an `Observable` so you have to `.subscribe()` to it in order the `pipe` to be called.